# How to properly set bearer API token as an environment variable in K8 pod

Tags: bash, docker, api, kubernetes, yaml

I have a major problem and will do my best to be short in the explanation. I am running a cronjob on an endpoint and would like to containerize that process. The endpoint needs to have some environments variables set and obviously a `TOKEN` authentication which is basically the login before I can curl POST or GET to get what I want from the API. The tricky part is that that TOKEN is never the same which means I need to run a curl command to get it during the pod run time. To make sure those environments variables are there in run time I injected a command in the cronjob args field to keep it running. When I ssh to the pod all my all env var are there ;) but the `TOKEN` :( . When I run `./run.sh` from inside the pod nothing happens which is the reason the TOKEN isn't listed in `printenv`. However when I manually run `command 1` then `command 2` from inside the pod it works fine. I am very confused and please help me if you can please. Instead of running my commands as a bash in the `cmd` at the docker level, I have seen that I can possibly parse `command 1` and `command 2` from the `run.sh` inside my cronjob.yaml with a multi line block scalar but haven't figured how as yaml format are a pain. Below are my codes for more details:

**docker-entrypoint.sh** --> removed

```
#! /bin/sh
export AWS_REGION=$AWS_REGION
export API_VS_HD=$API_VS_HD
export CONTROLLER_IP=$CONTROLLER_IP
export PASSWORD=$PASSWORD
export UUID=$UUID
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM harbor/ops5/private/:device-purge/python38:3.8

# Use root user for packages installation
USER root

# Install packages
RUN yum update -y && yum upgrade -y

# Install curl
RUN yum install curl -y \
    && curl --version

# Install zip/unzip/gunzip
RUN yum install zip unzip -y \
    && yum install gzip -y

# Install wget 
RUN yum install wget -y

# Install jq
RUN wget -O jq https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/download/jq-1.6/jq-linux64
RUN chmod +x ./jq
RUN cp jq /usr/bin

# Install aws cli
RUN curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
RUN unzip awscliv2.zip
RUN ./aws/install

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /home/app

# Add user
RUN groupadd --system user && adduser --system user --no-create-home --gid user
RUN chown -R user:user /home/app && chmod -R 777 /home/app

# Copy app
COPY ./run.sh /home/app 
RUN chmod +x /home/app/run.sh

# Switch to non-root user
USER user

# Run service
CMD ["sh", "-c", "./run.sh"]
```

**run.sh**

```
# Command 1
export TOKEN=`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "${API_VS_HD}" --request POST --data "{\"providerName\":\"local\",\"username\":\"admin\",\"password\":\"$PASSWORD\",\"deviceId\":\"$UUID\"}" https://$CONTROLLER_IP:444/admin/login --insecure | jq -r '.token'`

# Sleep 
sleep 3

# Command 2
curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
         -H "$API_VS_HD" \
         -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
         -X GET \
         https://$CONTROLLER_IP:444/admin/license/users
```

cronjob.yaml

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: device-cron-job
  namespace: device-purge
spec:
  schedule: "*/2 * * * *" # test
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          imagePullSecrets:
          - name: cron
          containers:
          - name: device-cron-pod
            image: harbor/ops5/private/:device-purge
            env:
            - name: AWS_REGION
              value: "us-east-1"
            - name: API_VS_HD
              value: "Accept:application/vnd.appgate.peer-v13+json"
            - name: CONTROLLER_IP
              value: "52.61.245.214"
            - name: UUID
              value: "d2b78ec2-####-###-###-#########"
            - name: PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef: 
                  name: password
                  key: password
            imagePullPolicy: Always
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
      backoffLimit: 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`run.sh` is never being called.  `docker-entrypoint.sh` needs to exec `run.sh` by adding `exec $@` at the bottom.  But you don't really need the entrypoint anyways, those environment variables are already being exported into your environment by docker.  I'm also not sure why you are specifying `command` and `args` in your yaml spec but I would get rid of those.

When you provide both an `ENTRYPOINT` and a `CMD` command in this form, the `CMD` params are passed to the entrypoint file, which then has the responsibility of executing the necessary process.  You can review the documentation [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your custom entrypoint is preventing `run.sh` from running, and the script itself doesn't specify the interpreter.

You can try:

```
#Switch back to default entrypoint
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh"]

#Actually run run.sh
# NOTE THE INITIAL dot (.) after "-c"
CMD ["-c",". docker-entrypoint.sh && ./run.sh"]
```

And delete the k8s CronJob `command` and associated `args` (you can also achieve the same in the CronJob yaml, but I prefer to have containers ready to do their job rather than specifying the CMD at k8s level.

You can also make `run.sh` easier to run by `/bin/sh` by indicating how to run it in the first line and importing the env vars there (I guess this is why it doesn't run when you type `./run.sh`):

```
#!/bin/sh

# Note the initial dot '.'
. docker-entrypoint.sh

# Command 1
[...]

# Command 2
[...]
```

Another suggestion is to define the environment variables defined in `docker-entrypoint.sh` at k8s CronJob yaml level. This considered best practice to define env variables in k8s pods. You can make use k8s secrets when the value of the variable is sensitive.

Comment: Thank you both for the feedback . To make it work I removed the `docker-entrypoint` and ran my commands from the `CMD` as as default executable then removed the `args` and `command` from the cron yaml. God Bless you both ;).. I also updated the final codes I've used  above for anybody interested.

Comment: Hey @kddiji , glad it helped! If answers were useful to you, would you consider upvoting?